# PyTorch nn.module won't unbatch operations

Tags: python, pytorch, array-broadcasting

I have a nn.Module whose `forward` function takes in two inputs. Inside the function, I multiply one of the inputs `x1` by a set of trainable parameters, and then concatenate them with the other input `x2`.

```
class ConcatMe(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pad_len, emb_size):
        super(ConcatMe, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(pad_len, emb_size).to(DEVICE), requires_grad=True)
        self.emb_size = emb_size
     
    def forward(self, x1: Tensor, x2: Tensor):
        cat = self.W * torch.reshape(x2, (1, -1, 1))
        return torch.cat((x1, cat), dim=-1)
```

From my understanding, one is supposed to be able to write operations in PyTorch's nn.Modules like we would for inputs with a batch size of 1. For some reason, this is not the case. I'm getting an error that indicates that PyTorch is still accounting for batch_size.

```
x1 =  torch.randn(100,2,512)
x2 = torch.randint(10, (2,1))
concat = ConcatMe(100, 512)
concat(x1, x2)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File "/home/my/file/path.py, line 0, in forward
    cat = self.W * torch.reshape(x2, (1, -1, 1))
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (100) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I made a for loop to patch the issue as shown below:

```
class ConcatMe(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pad_len, emb_size):
        super(ConcatMe, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(pad_len, emb_size).to(DEVICE), requires_grad=True)
        self.emb_size = emb_size
     
    def forward(self, x1: Tensor, x2: Tensor):
        batch_size = x2.shape[0]
        cat = torch.ones(x1.shape).to(DEVICE)

        for i in range(batch_size):
            cat[:, i, :] = self.W * x2[i]

        return torch.cat((x1, cat), dim=-1)
```

but I feel like there's a more elegant solution. Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm creating parameters inside nn.Module? If so, what solution can I implement that doesn't require a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, one is supposed to be able to write operations in PyTorch's `nn.Module`s like we would for inputs with a batch size of *1*.

I'm not sure where you got this assumption, it is definitely *not* true - on the contrary: you always need to write them in a way that they can handle the general case of an arbitrary batch dimension.

Judging from your second implementation it seems like you're trying to multiply two tensors with incompatible dimensions. So in order to fix that you'd have to define

```
        self.W = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(pad_len, 1, emb_size), requires_grad=True)
```

To understand things like that better it would help to learn about [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html).

Comment: Thank you, broadcasting did the trick. Also, here's where I read that we could define operations in nn.Modules as operating on batch_size=1: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/do-i-need-to-consider-the-batch-size-when-defining-own-module/16292

Comment: Ok I see, there is a detail that is easy to overlook: During *initialization* (mostly of the built in Modules) you usually don't care about the actual batch size, but when when you actually start using your own operations and tensors then you should definitely be aware of it. In any case, just assuming that the batch size is one is not a good idea, there are operations that work well if the batch size is 1 but can fail if it is anything other than 1.